# password protection using PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512 is taking lot of processing time on production setup(AWS)

Tags: java, password-encryption, aws-sdk

I am trying to securely store my user's password using following steps

1. Salting+hashing+ stretching using PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512
2. Iteration of 20,000

My code is pasted below

```
public class EncrypterClass
{
    private static final int iterations = 20000;
    private static final int saltLen = 64;
    private static final int desiredKeyLen = 512;

    private static String hash(String value, byte[] salt) throws Exception 
    {
        if (value == null || value.length() == 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Empty passwords are not supported.");
        SecretKeyFactory f = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
        SecretKey key = f.generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec(value.toCharArray(), salt, iterations, desiredKeyLen));
        return Base64.encodeBase64String(key.getEncoded());
    }

    public static class Password
    {
        public static String getSaltedPassword( String password ) throws Exception 
        {
            byte[] salt = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG").generateSeed(saltLen);        
            return Base64.encodeBase64String(salt) + "$" + hash(password, salt);
        }

        public static boolean match(String password, String saltedPassword) throws Exception
        {
            String[] saltAndPass = saltedPassword.split("\\$");
            if (saltAndPass.length != 2) 
            {
                return false;
            }
            String hashOfInput = hash(password, Base64.decodeBase64(saltAndPass[0]));
            return hashOfInput.equals(saltAndPass[1]);
        }
    } 
}
```

It works fine when i test it on my local machine. But on my AWS setup flow is getting into some kind of time consuming processing (for several minutes to hash the password). Currently my AWS setup is a free test setup with following resources: **EC2 t2.micro with 1 vCPU and 1GiB**

Can someone guide what may be the problem ?

thanks
Amit

Answer (score 1):

This salt + hash algorithm, especially with so many iterations, is slow by design, and on purpose: the goal is precisely to make it very computationally hard for an attacker to find the password by doing a brute-force attack. On a resource-limited VM, it will obviously be even slower.

Comment: but i used the same code with private static final int iterations = 2; then same problem is there.what is the standard time of one iteration.

Comment: Maybe the time is caused by the secure random computation. I've had issues with Linux VMs looking for entropy for several minutes. Measure.